# Filter for User Domain Name in LDAPv3 (not AD)

Tags: ldap, opendirectory

I try to get my UID out of the LDAP by a filter that can recognize the whole user with the (internal) domain. For example: (Internal) LDAP Domain is "office.intern" and the user (uid) is "peter.pan" and email is "peter.pan@office.com". But i want to search/filter for **"peter.pan@office.intern"** as the whole qualified domain user name **(User Principal Name)** to find "peter.pan". And i have no clue how the filter has to look like.

Can someone enlighten me. Please!!!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: When there is no attribute with a value of `peter.pan@office.intern` to search for, you shouldn't use that as the filter. -  Your options are then: before executing the ldap query either simply split the username at the `@` first and then search only for `peter.pan` or substitute the  office.intern for office.com and search for an email attribute with the value of `peter.pan@office.com`, and maybe limit your search results with the appropriate search base to find results only for office.intern

Comment: Hi Bob, thank you very much. I was afraid of this answer as i need the official email peter.pan@office.com for notifications and the peter.pan@office.intern as login for a crushftp server. And yes you are right i can query for "uid" and "mail" and this works because it is a value. I'm too new to this ldap filter match querry thing and thought there has to be a "workaround" in our digital world to "extract" the UPN. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Rather than a convoluted technical solution, how about simply instructing  your (FTP) users to use the login name that you actually know them by in your LDAP? i.e. *Dear mr. Pan please log in with `ftp://peter.pan:<password>@ftp.example.com`*

Comment: Hi Bob, thanks again for this idea. I'm sorry that i did not explain the whole thing. Yes your are right with your idea. But i was trying to figure out how i can login the internal domain user to the backend of the crush ftp for administration the server. And you couldn't know that. I'm sorry. BUT you gave me a very good hint! I hardcoded **peter.pan@office.intern** in the attribute type "departmentNumber" as it is not used. And now i can filter for the attribute. I have to say thank you for bringing me to an "ugly" workaround. :) But it works! THANK YOU.